# How do I change my "1" into "Period" in C#?

Tags: c#

This is the current output from my program:

```
Numbers in the table are in Millions
-------------------------------------------
1          4          5          6
-------------------------------------------
7          131.6      140.7      150.4
8          136.9      147.7      159.4
9          142.3      155.1      168.9
10         148        162.9      179.1
-------------------------------------------
```

My intention for variable `i` is to keep it in the first line, so I just lock the value in 1. But I want to change the display as seen above to the string, "Period", instead of 1.

Code:

```
//header
listBoxResult.Items.Add("Numbers in the table are in Millions");
listBoxResult.Items.Add("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
{
    string headerRow = i.ToString();
    for (int j = interestStart; j <= interestEnd; j++)
    {
        headerRow += "\t" + j;
    }
    listBoxResult.Items.Add(headerRow);
}
listBoxResult.Items.Add("- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -");
//calculation
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share your code as a snippet instead of image. Thanks.

Comment: Is there reason why you have the outer for loop there? Why not just start with `string headerRow = "Period";`?

Comment: I see, i forgot about it. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: You mean like `string headerRow = (i == 1?"Period":i.ToString());` ? That's called a ternary, like a small if, that does a test and returns one value if true and another value if false. They can be nested, by the way, but it's something you should avoid because it makes the code hard to follow; better to write "if else if else" blocks if you want complex decision paths

Comment: It's already done. just the `string headerRow = i.ToString()` is the problem. Changed it already to `string headerRow = "Period"`. Thank you for answering

Comment: I assumed that at some point the outer loop was going to have some purpose, and you'd just limited it to `i<=1` for debugging. You should remove the outer for loop; it does nothing useful if it starts i at 1, and runs only while i is 1

Comment: Also note, these are comments, not answers; your question is closed so no answers can be posted. It's quite important to refer to things by their proper names, in software engineering :)

Comment: i see..... Thank you about that.

Comment: So your question was ... "how do I print 'Period'?" ;-)